# Использование метода коллокации для решения ДУ

Tags: python, математика, numpy, matlab, физика

У меня есть следующее ДУ и задание к нему:
Определить методом коллокации приближенные решения следующих краевых задач.
Использовать следующие базовые функции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точки колокации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Базисные функции:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в этом во всем новичек поэтому нужна помощь!
Проблема в реализации...В интернете мало очень информации о реализации этого метода на python или матлабе.
Поэтому, уважаемые, прошу у вас помощи!

Еще формулы:

Решение ищем в виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она должна удовлетворять следующим условиям:
Неоднородные краевый условия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однородные краевые условия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будем требовать, чтобы невязка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(8.40) равнялась нулю на
некоторой системе точек
x1,x2, ... ,xn
отрезка[a;b],которые называются точками коллокации, причем количество таких точек должно быть равно числу коэффициентов ci в выражении (8.39)

Тогда для определения c1, c2, .., cn получаем
систему уравнений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я начал писать код:

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols('x')
y = sym.Function('y')(x)
eq = sym.Eq(sym.diff(y, x, 2) + sym.diff(y, x) - y / x - 8 * x * x + 8 * x - 1.5, 0)
sol = sym.dsolve(eq)
fc = sol.rhs
eq1 = sym.Eq(fc.subs({x: 0}), 0)
dfc = sym.diff(fc, x)
eq2 = sym.Eq(fc.subs({x: 1}), 1)
csol = sym.solve([eq1, eq2], dict=True)
fres = fc.subs(csol[0])
print(fres)
```

Но я получаю следующую ошибку

```
raise NotImplementedError("The given ODE " + str(eq) + " cannot be solved by"
NotImplementedError: The given ODE -8.0*x**2 + 8.0*x + Derivative(y(x), x) + Derivative(y(x), (x, 2)) - 1.5 - y(x)/x cannot be solved by the factorable group method
```

Comment: Совершенно непонятно на каком шаге решения у вас возникла сложность. Из-за этого непонятно как дать полезный ответ. Напишите хоть какие-то свои мысли, по поводу задачи...

Comment: Я не очень понимаю с чего мне начинать.
А именно в реализации кода.

Answer (score 0):

0. Убедитесь (на бумажке, либо с использованием пакета символьных вычислений), что базис u0...u3 удовлетворяет граничному условию (8.37)
1. В исходном дифф. у-е вычтите левую часть из правой, получите выражения для функции невязки R(x, y(x), y'(x), y''(x)).
2. Вычислить (аналичтически или символьно) две первых производных для функций u0(x)...u3(x)
3. Выразите y''(x) и y'(x) через производные ui(x) и Ci
4. Подставьте выражения для y''(x), y'(x), y(x), из п.3 в выражение для R
5. Подставьте выражения для u''(x), u'(x), u(x), полученные в п.2 в выражение для R. Получите выражение для R(x, C1, C2, C3). В силу линейности исходного дифф. у-я. по y, полученное выражение будет линейным относительно переменных C1, C2, C3. (Коэффициенты будут зависеть от x.)
6. Перепишите выражение для R(x, C1, C2, C3) в форме: `R(x, C1, C2, C3)=g0(x) + g1(x)*C1 + g2(x)*C3 + g4(x)*C4`
7. Поставив в выражение из п.6 конкретные значения x (из массива точек коллокации) получите систему линейных уравнений, относительно переменных Ci.
8. Решаем систему. (численно)
9. Поставляем  найденные Ci в выражение для y(x) - это и есть ответ.

Пункты 1-6 можно выполнять либо аналитически (на бумажке, получится пара страниц), либо с использованием пакетов символьных вычислений (sympy - в питоне), но это потребует затрат времени на освоение пакета.

Пункты 7-9 - реализуете численно, в виде программы.

Comment: Я начал писать посмотрите если можете.
Также я не нашел в пакете sympy  как проверить что базис u0...u3 удовлетворяет граничному условию